# Replace all elements in a string except N, n and spaces in python

Tags: python, if-statement, replace

I want to replace all elements in a string with a # except for N and n. This is the code that i have been working

```
test_str = ("BaNana")
for x in test_str:
    if x != "n" or x !="N":
        ari = test_str.replace(x, "#")
        print(ari)
```

The output that i get is

```
    #aNana
    B#N#n#
    Ba#ana
    B#N#n#
    B#N#n#
```

Where as the output that i want is

```
    ##N#n#
```

Comment: `!(n or N)` is the same as `!n and !N`, not `!n or !N`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: `'N'` is not equal to `'n'` and so you will enter the `if` for any of those two letters also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@schwobaseggl answer is short version of below. In python strings are immutable. So `replace` function would create new instance of string every time.

```
test_str = ("BaNana")
temp_list=[]
for x in test_str:
    if x != "n" and  x !="N":
        temp_list.append("#")
    else:
        temp_list.append(x)


new_str= "".join(temp_list)
print(new_str)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use character class `[^Nn]` with the preceeding negation operator `^` to replace every character **except** `N` and `n` like below,

```
import re
regex = r"([^Nn])"
test_str = "BaNana"
subst = "#"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print (result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
##N#n#
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://rextester.com/NXW57388

Answer (score 2):

Without regex, simple `str.join` with a conditional generator:

```
''.join(c if c in 'nN' else '#' for c in 'BaNana')
# '##N#n#'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a negated character class only without a capturing group `[^Nn]` and replace with `#`.

No need for using `re.MULTILINE` as there are no anchors in the pattern.

```
import re
result = re.sub(r"[^Nn]", "#", "BaNana")
print(result)
```

Output

```
##N#n#
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/Lh5203)

Answer (score 1):

Although @AlwaysSunny's answer is correct, here is your code fixed:

```
test_str = ("BaNana")
for x in test_str:
    if x != "n" and x !="N":
        test_str = test_str.replace(x, "#")
    print(test_str)
```

and the output:

```
#aNana
##N#n#
##N#n#
##N#n#
##N#n#
##N#n#
```

Even better would be:

```
test_str = ("BaNana")
for x in test_str:
    if x != "n" and x !="N":
        test_str = test_str.replace(x, "#")
print(test_str)
```

for the output:

```
##N#n#
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) docs:

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old
>   replaced by new

So for each character you create a new string where this character is replaced. What you can do, is simply add the desired letters and for any other letter add `'#'`:

```py
test_str = ("BaNana")
ari = ""
for x in test_str:
    if x.lower() == "n":
        ari += x
    else:
        ari += "#"
print(ari)
```